# Kubernetes with cert-manager and nginx

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am attempting to setup jetstack/cert-manager on kubernetes.
This will provide the certificates for multiple of my subdomains.
It has worked great until I needed to create an nginx.conf file.

What happens now is that all the requests from cert-manager to `http://www.redacted.com/.well-know/challenge/xx` are handled by my application pod, rather than the cert-manager pods.

Does anyone know how I can keep an nginx config file, but let all .well-known requests be handled by the cert-manager pods?
It seems that if I could choose the order of the ingresses, I could set the priority on my application ingress to last, so that the automatically created cert-manager ingresses get run first.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out and it of course wasn't an issue with cert-manager!

I had my root domain e.g. `<redacted>.com` automatically redirecting to `www.<redacted>.com`, but was also trying to generate a certificate at `<redacted>.com` as well as for the subdomains. Cert-manager failed because it couldn't reach the .well-known/acme-challenge of the root domain as it was being redirected.

The way I plan on solving this is generating the root certificate through DNS not HTTP, and that way the certificate will still be valid for `<redacted>.com` and I can still forward both http and https connections to the www subdomain.